# Python: Formatting Console Input

Tags: python, text, console, formatting, center

Good Afternoon,

I'm just currently playing around with Python and wanted to know if it is possible to format the location of where a user types their input.

For example, when they are typing their name I want it to be typed in the center like the rest of the text is (see below picture)

[image]

Is it possible to center the user input?

Thank You!
Josh

Comment: Your best bet is to use a library like Curses. Otherwise, you'll need to fiddle around with ANSI escape codes, or a similar method.

Comment: hhhmmm... add spaces depend on the console width and text input and trim it when you want to assign the value...